# Nested Binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Find the remainder when $P= \displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{42} \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{2}$ is divided by 10.

I went down the obvious, brute force method of writing $\binom{k}{2}=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ and ended up with $$\frac 18 \sum_{n=3}^{42}(n^4-2n^3+3n^2-2n)$$ and applied the power sum formulas. The algebra got really messy.

Can anyone provide a faster calculation of the above method or some other innovative procedure? Geometric or combinatorial interpretations like the first amswer of [Combinatorial Geometric proof of $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{3} > \binom{\binom{n}{3}}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4228854/combinatorial-geometric-proof-of-binom-binomn23-binom-binomn3) are also appreciated.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I *loved* writing that answer. There will be some combinatorial interpretation of that sum. The hint below contains some details, but the reason is rather simple : it's a sum of polynomials in $n$ (and one can decipher the degree fairly easily), so I do expect something combinatorial to come out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$P_k= \displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{k} \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{40} (k-2) (k-1) k (k+1) (k+2)$$ could help

Comment: How did you get that????

Comment: @insipidintegrator. Your summand is already $\frac{1}{8} (n-2) (n-1) n (n+1)$$

Comment: The solution was at first, pretty far away from my reach. So, I used a telescope to see the solution. Thanks!